# How to fix "failed to load cairo DLL" in R?

Tags: r, cairo

I am running into this warning message that will stop execution.

```
Saving 8.04 x 5.67 in image
Warning messages:
1: In dev(file = filename, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.0_1/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':

  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.0_1/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so, 6): image not found
2: In dev(file = filename, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], ...) :
  failed to load cairo DLL
```

---

This is the code that generates that warning for me

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

d <- sample_n(diamonds, 50)
g <- ggplot(d, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point()
gg <- list(g,g,g)

plot_grid(plotlist = gg, nrow=1) %>% 
  cowplot::ggsave(filename = paste0("~/Desktop/", paste0("testing", ".svg")), device = cairo_ps)
```

How do I go about fixing this error?

P.s. I am a novice.

EDIT:
This is my session information. I am not sure if this would be helpful. I have included it just in case.

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] cowplot_0.9.2     forcats_0.3.0     stringr_1.3.1     dplyr_0.7.5      
 [5] purrr_0.2.5       readr_1.1.1       tidyr_0.8.1       tibble_1.4.2     
 [9] ggplot2_2.2.1     tidyverse_1.2.1   doParallel_1.0.11 iterators_1.0.9  
[13] foreach_1.4.4     lmerTest_3.0-1    lme4_1.1-17       Matrix_1.2-14    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.4  reshape2_1.4.3    splines_3.5.0     haven_1.1.1      
 [5] lattice_0.20-35   argparse_1.1.1    colorspace_1.3-2  getopt_1.20.2    
 [9] yaml_2.1.19       rlang_0.2.1       nloptr_1.0.4      pillar_1.2.3     
[13] foreign_0.8-70    glue_1.2.0        readxl_1.1.0      modelr_0.1.2     
[17] bindrcpp_0.2.2    bindr_0.1.1       plyr_1.8.4        cellranger_1.1.0 
[21] munsell_0.4.3     findpython_1.0.3  gtable_0.2.0      rvest_0.3.2      
[25] codetools_0.2-15  psych_1.8.4       labeling_0.3      broom_0.4.4      
[29] proto_1.0.0       Rcpp_0.12.17      scales_0.5.0      jsonlite_1.5     
[33] mnormt_1.5-5      hms_0.4.2         stringi_1.2.2     numDeriv_2016.8-1
[37] grid_3.5.0        cli_1.0.0         tools_3.5.0       magrittr_1.5     
[41] lazyeval_0.2.1    crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.1   MASS_7.3-49      
[45] xml2_1.2.0        lubridate_1.7.4   rstudioapi_0.7    assertthat_0.2.0 
[49] minqa_1.2.4       httr_1.3.1        R6_2.2.2          nlme_3.1-137     
[53] compiler_3.5.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure about macOS... but do you have cairo installed in your system?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952427/include-cairo-r-on-a-mac)?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I have looked through a multitude of online resources trying to debug this issue. I do have `cairo` installed on my computer - through `homebrew`. I also have reinstalled my versions of `Quartz`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only have a Windows machine to offer, but the following worked for both saving a `.svg` and `.eps` of your cowplot (after installing the package `svglite`):

```
# install.packages(svglite)
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

d <- sample_n(diamonds, 50)
g <- ggplot(d, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point()
gg <- list(g,g,g)

plot_grid(plotlist = gg, nrow=1)
ggsave(filename = "testing.svg")
ggsave(filename = "testing.eps")
```

You can of course modify the filename to something like `"~/Desktop/testing.svg"`, depending on where you want to safe your plot. Note that `ggsave` per default saves the last active plot, and the ending of the filename you specify should automatically trigger the right device.

Comment: Yes! This worked for me! I was for some reason - setting `device = cairo_ps` was the main problem. If anyone in the future is reading this, I guess just let the internal workings of `ggsave` handle your filename by the ending `.svg` or `.etc`.

Answer (score 13):

The Homebrew version of R no longer supports `cairo` ([more info here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/19557)), so graphical devices like `svg()`, `cairo_pdf()`, and `cairo_ps()` in base R won't work if you install R via `brew install r`. You have to use other graphical devices (e.g., `png`, `jpeg`, `pdf`). If you need SVG output, `ggsave()` requires the **svglite** package and uses `svglite::svglite()` to save your plot to an SVG file.

If you do want to use Homebrew to install R, I recommend `brew install --cask r`.

Comment: This error also happens with the official R directly from CRAN.

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem and I use *MacOS*.  I found it is *XQuartz* related *"since it is no longer part of OS X"*, according to CRAN.  I installed *XQuartz* and basically all *Cairo* related problems are addressed.

Comment: Had the same "failed to load cairo DLL" error. Installing XQuartz (on Mac OS) solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on my M1 Mac in May 2022: `brew install --cask xquartz`

Comment: Can confirm, you can just install this on macOS (I have an M2 processor), especially if don't have or want `brew`. Site: https://www.xquartz.org.