# Export chord diagram as .svg

Tags: r, chord-diagram

I've inherited a script to create a circos/chord diagram in R. I have very basic knowledge of R...

The R studio export options seem to not work except for .png. I need an editable version (.svg or .eps) but the former [crashes](https://community.rstudio.com/t/plots-crash-while-exporting-as-svg/15504), and the latter exports without the connections.

I can't figure out how to run the plot code and save it in the command line. I've tried to use the svglite package (see below) and also just `svg(filename="Std_SVG.svg")` but it's either not working and not throwing any errors or coming up with `failed to load cairo DLL`. Which I can't seem to figure out a way around. Any help please?

```
svglite(tempfile("chord_test.svg"))
chordDiagramFromMatrix(f, transparency = 0.5, annotationTrack = c('grid'), 
                       symmetric = TRUE, grid.col = node_col,
                       col = colours, keep.diagonal = TRUE, preAllocateTracks = 1)

circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + .1, sector.name, facing = "clockwise", 
              niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex = 1.6)}, bg.border = NA)
circos.clear()
dev.off()
```

Comment: Do you have the `Cairo` package installed and loaded?

Comment: Yes, I did have that. It doesn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: No it turns out I didn't have that! Thank you for pointing it out, there was an error I had missed and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952427/include-cairo-r-on-a-mac was the answer. Thank you!