# Unable to load R Package: 'pdftools'

Tags: r, data-analysis, text-mining, pdftools

First time posting here and new to R.

I am having trouble with loading pdftools into R studio for text mining.

#1 - I am able to install the package successfully

#2 - Once I attempt to load`library(pdftools)` I receive the following output.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pdftools’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/pdftools/libs/pdftools.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/pdftools/libs/pdftools.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/pdftools/libs/pdftools.so
Reason: tried: '/opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libXrender.1.dylib' (no such file)
```

Additional Details:
Machine: MacBook Pro (2022) M1 Max
Software: macOS Monterey Version 12.3.1.
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963676/12957340) installing xquartz may solve the problem. To get xquartz to run on an M1 silicon macbook: https://appletoolbox.com/run-xquartz-m1-mac/

Comment: @r2evans - thank you, it worked! I downloaded xquartz, installed it through terminal, and successfully loaded in R. Thank you!

Comment: really you should be thanking @jared_mamrot ... all I did was remove the errant [tag:rstudio] tag :-)